# No link to bypass 'Your connection isn't private'

Tags: browser, connection, blocking, private-browsing

Sometime trying to get to a site I'm getting a message about not private connection. On the Internet there is information that there should be link to a site if you unfold the message (click on the button below). But I don't have the link.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: There maybe a problem with your sdl certificate. Please post the url you are using, the nrowser you are using and some details of your site

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta https://www.torproject.org/download/, any browser has this issue.

Comment: @Community the problem is that I can't get to the site.

Comment: The link to bypass isn’t visible because the site is served with HTTP Strict Transport Security headers, as explained in the last paragraph of the error message. // You can try retrieving the certificate chain that you see and provide it in the question, so we can inspect it. // Are you aware of any HTTPS-inspecting software on your system or on your connection to the internet?

Comment: Try to clear the HSTS settings for this website as explained for example in [this article](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/).